# С чем сравнивается поле объекта book?

Tags: c#, .net, ооп

Дан код, который сравнивает object'ы, а именно книги. В методе `CompareTo` есть условие где, `book.Theme` сравнивается с `Theme`. С чем сравнивается объект `book.Theme`?

```
public class Book : IComparable
    {
        public string Title;
        public int Theme;
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            var book = (Book)obj;
            if (book.Theme.CompareTo(Theme) == 0)
                return -(book.Title.CompareTo(Title));
            else
                return -(book.Theme.CompareTo(Theme));
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    internal class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            var temp = new Book() { Theme = 7,Title = "B" };
            var temp2 = new Book() {Theme = 4, Title = "B"};
            object obj = temp;`введите сюда код`
            object obj2 = temp2;
            Console.WriteLine(temp2.CompareTo(obj));
        }
    }
```

Comment: ты же сам пишешь, что _book.Theme сравнивается с Theme_, прямо перед вопросом _С чем сравнивается объект book.Theme_

Comment: Подразумевается `this.Theme`.